# ParseError: Unexpected end tag - How to clean html tags?

Tags: html, dreamweaver, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal

I'm starting to learn web development and am using pyramid with chameleon.  I just took some sites html source as a template in Dreamweaver and then copied the code into a chameleon .pt file.

The html code displays fine in dreamweaver but I get this error when running it in pyramid:

```
chameleon.exc.ParseError
ParseError: Unexpected end tag.

 - String:     "</div>"
```

I have tried dreamweavers cleanup function and it said it removed 2 empty tags but I still get this error.  My traceback is all related to errors in the chameleon and doesn't show the specific line its having problems with in my template itself.

Is there a way to identify the actual line where the error is occurring?

I'm not sure if there's a pyramid or chameleon specific solution or if there are general methods to find errors in HTML tag.

Comment: you could always run it through mako or jinja2 instead as they are much less strict on the well-formedness of the html

Comment: @MichaelMerickel Thanks for the suggestion.  I thought about different templating engines but wasn't sure because it seemed like Pyramid was leaning towards Chameleon.  I just started learning so I don't really care what I learn as long as it works well and will be supported for a while.  Do you think mako or jinga2 are better choices? if so, is there one you would suggest?

Comment: @MichaelMerickel by the way..code works fine in Jinja2 but still not sure which one I want to go with. I read performance reviews and they seem similar but not sure which one has a bigger community or will be supported for longer(jinja2 has 300 questions on this site while mako has 150 but not sure if thats an good indicator).

Comment: All 3 are stable and well supported, and pyramid is utterly indifferent to what engine you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chameleon expects templates to be well-formed, and is less forgiving of unbalanced tags and incorrect attribute markup as DreamWeaver is.

Note that the error doesn't necessarily mean that there is a `</div>` tag too many. If the opening `<div>` has a syntax error such as a missing `=` on an attribute declaration (e.g. `<div class"foobar">` then the opening tag is not recognized and the corresponding closing tag is going to be flagged as well.

You could run your template through an XML validator, there are several available online (such as http://www.validome.org/xml/, http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and http://xmlgrid.net/, [Google lists many more](http://www.google.com/search?q=online+xml+syntax+check)). These are bound to give you a slightly more helpful message as to what is wrong with your template.

Answer (score 1):

Never used pyramid/chameleon before, but it looks like you have to go through the code and remove an extra `</div>` tag. When you get the message that it removed two empty tags, that probably means it removed the open and closing of a set of tags

e.g. `<div></div>` or `<p></p>`

Go through your code and for every `<div>` there should be a `</div>`.

Comment: This code is very large(15,000+ lines).  I'm asking for a way to avoid having to go through that many lines of code manually. I understand the browsers are forgiving but hoping the error/line number is generated somewhere.